# datatables.net loading row headings and data in same AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, vb.net, datatables

Hey all I am trying to use the **[datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/)** to populate a table with my needed data.

I have my data coming out like so:

```
{
   "headings": [
     "First Name","Last Name"
   ],
   "results": [
     "bart",
     "simpson"
   ],
   [
     "New",
     "Record"
   ],
   [
     "Someone",
     "Here"
   ],
   [
     "test",
     "test"
   ]
}
```

My javascript is this:

```
$('#theDataTable').dataTable({
   "ajax": 'default.aspx?Data=viewData'
});
```

I'm sure there is a way of doing this - though I am not really seeing an example on the website (or just overlooking it)?

Any help to do this would be great!

Comment: Not actually used it myself, but it looks like you can use [columns.title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) (or `sTitle` if using v1.9)

Comment: @markpsmith But thats hard-coded in there and not taken from the AJAX call itself.